# Php output script need to modify

Tags: php

This script in php

```
$name = "\"".$line["name"]."\" ";
```

giving this output  :-  "namefromdb"

i want output like this :-  namefromdb

No inverted commas

Comment: try this: `$name = $line["name"];` do you really know PHP?

Comment: Don't concatenate your variable with quotes then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get \namefromdb\ then use

```
<?php
$name = '\\'.$line['name'].'\\';
?>
```

If you're trying to get just namefromdb then use

```
<?php 
$name = $line['name'];
?>
```

You have to be more descriptive with your posts, explain what you're trying to do... and what you want the output to be...

Comment: When i do this your way no output , and when i do this way $name = '\' '.$line["name"].'\'';                                         Then the output come like =  'namefromdb'

Comment: $name = $line['name'];